# How to call js and css file and replace the script in code

Tags: blocks

I'm trying to display a map in node page, it's working but the code doesn't look professional.

```
function customodule_block_info() {
    $blocks['customodule'] = array(
        'info' => t('Google Map Exemple'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
    );
    return $blocks;
}

function customodule_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'customodule':
            $block['content'] = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
  #map_canvas { height: 560px; width: 100%  }
    #map_canvas img {
max-width: none;

}

    #map_canvas div {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<div data-role="page">


<div data-role="content">
  <div id="map_canvas" ></div>
</div><!-- /content -->

 <!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>';


    };
    return $block;
}
```

I want to know how **hook_block_view** can read the css and js files?

Comment: use durpal_add_css() or drupal_add_js() function to add css or js

Comment: how and where? i used it but it's not worked :(

Comment: in your module folder create css/js files and using above mention function define in your module file

Comment: i know , i try it but she doesent work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the JS and CSS files and then in the block view add them in the following way:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/css/my_css_file.css');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') .'/js/my_js_file.js', 'file');
```

We have done something similar at a module we develop:
[Guardian news](https://github.com/ichionid/Guardian-news/blob/0d0b2552403b4e652d9174d227d962559d44f6c5/guardian_news.module)